# JQuery DataTables and Jeditable - fields contains html but should not. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables, jeditable

I am using DataTables and Jeditbale.  Everything seems to work well, however, for some reason when I double-click any field within the table, it contains HTML.  I have inserted the visual herein.  I have not tried anything to fix this problem as I cannot even understand how this would occur.  I have googled the problem but most people who report a similar problem just report extra blank spaces; not full html in fields.  How can I fix this?  If additional code required, can add in due course. [image]

Here is my table code:

```
<!-- start table listing -->
            <table id="myTable" class="stripe hover cell-border row-border">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th id="country_id">Country ID</th> 
                        <th id="country">Country Name</th>  
                        <th id="country_import">Import Commnents</th>
                        <th id="country_export">Export Comments</th>
                        <th id="country_date_created">Created</th>
                        <th id="country_date_updated">Updated</th>
                        <th id="">Updated by</th>
                        <th id="country_enabled">Enabled?</th>
                        <th id="">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <?php
                    foreach ($query as $row ) {
                ?>
                    <tr <?php echo 'id="'.$row->country_id.'"'; ?> > 


                        <td>    
                            <?php echo $row->country_id; ?>
                        </td>


                        <td>    
                            <a class='table-action-deletelink' href='/admin/country_view/<?php echo ''.$row->country_id.''; ?> '><?php echo $row->country; ?></a>
                        </td>



                        <td>    
                            <?php echo $row->country_import_comments; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>    
                            <?php echo $row->country_export_comments; ?>
                        </td>

                        <td>    
                            <?php echo $row->country_date_created; ?>
                        </td>

                        <td>    
                            <?php echo $row->country_date_last_updated; ?>
                        </td>

                        <td>    
                            <?php echo $row->country_updated_by; ?>
                        </td>






                        <td>    <?php 
                                if ($row->country_enabled == 1) {
                                    echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" ></span>';
                                } else {
                                    echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true" ></span>';
                                } ?>
                        </td>




                        <td>


                        <!-- main container -->
                        <div class="dropdown">
                          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                            Dropdown
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                          </button>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/admin/country_view/<?php echo ''.$row->country_id.''; ?>">View</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Edit</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Deactivate</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/admin/country_delete/<?php echo ''.$row->country_id.''; ?> ">Delete</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>


                        </td>

            </form>


                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>            
            </table>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript that implements the table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //sDeleteURL: "/Home/DeleteData.php"
    $('#myTable').dataTable().makeEditable( {
        // some basic config
        'bProcessing':      true, 
        'bServerSide':      true, 
         'sAjaxSource':     "admin/json_get_countries",

        stateSave:          true,
        "scrollCollapse":   true,
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
            "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
            "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No records available",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
            }
    } );
} );  // end of on doc load
```

Comment: Can you show the code how you construct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [jQuery DataTables Editable plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wiki/Overview) which internally uses [jQuery Jeditable plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable).

According to [Jeditable documentation](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) (see **Usage with Textile, Markdown, ReST, WiKi**), if field contains content other than plain text (HTML, Markdown, etc), you need to use `loadurl` parameter to load content in  and `sUpdateURL` to save modified value.

See [Editable DataTable example - custom editors](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/custom-editors.html) on how `Engine version` field is being edited and saved by using URLs specified in `loadurl` and `sUpdateURL` parameters.

You can make certain columns read-only and not-editable by defining `aoColumns` option and specifying `null` for corresponding column. `aoColumns` is an array holding options for all columns in sequential order, length of this array must be equal to the number of columns in the original HTML table.

Example:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   $('#example').dataTable().makeEditable({
      sUpdateURL: "UpdateData.php",
      "aoColumns": [
            null,
            {
            },
            {
               indicator: 'Saving platforms...',
               tooltip: 'Click to edit platforms',
               type: 'textarea',
               submit:'Save changes',
               fnOnCellUpdated: function(sStatus, sValue, settings){
                  alert("(Cell Callback): Cell is updated with value " + sValue);
               }
            },
            {
               //indicator: 'Saving Engine Version...',
               tooltip: 'Click to select engine version',
               loadtext: 'loading...',
               type: 'select',
               onblur: 'cancel',
               submit: 'Ok',
               loadurl: 'EngineVersionList.php',
               loadtype: 'GET',
               sUpdateURL: "CustomUpdateEngineVersion.php"
            },
            {
               indicator: 'Saving CSS Grade...',
               tooltip: 'Click to select CSS Grade',
               loadtext: 'loading...',
               type: 'select',
               onblur: 'submit',
               data: "{'':'Please select...', 'A':'A','B':'B','C':'C'}",
               sUpdateURL: function(value, settings){
                  alert("Custom function for posting results");
                  return value;

               }
            }
      ]                          
   });
})
```

See [answer to similar problem with Jeditable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868294/3549014). However this answer targets Jeditable only and not jQuery DataTables Editable plugin, so the code shown there doesn't apply, just the explanation.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem!  I tried with a json response and it works.  Thanks you!